# ofType is not a function in testing with rxjs marble diagrams

Tags: redux, rxjs, rxjs6, redux-observable

I am using rxjs 6 with redux-observable 1 and write test for epic

```
const signInEpic = action$ =>
  action$
    .ofType(authActions.signIn)
    .pipe(
      switchMap(mapSignInAction$)
    )
```

I am using TestScheduler for testing by marble diagrams and when run test it return error `action$.ofType is not a function`

test:

```
import { TestScheduler } from 'rxjs/testing'

const scheduler = new TestScheduler((actual, expected) => {
  expect(actual).toEqual(expected)
})

scheduler.run(({ cold, hot, expectObservable }) => {
    const action$ = hot('-a', { a: { type: 'HFJKDHF' } })
    const state$ = null
    const output$ = signInEpic(action$, state$)

    expectObservable(output$).toBe('--b', {
      b: actions.signInSuccess(response)
    })
  })
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead `action$.ofType` need use `action$.pipe(ofType(...), ...)`

```
import { ofType } from 'redux-observable'

action$
    .pipe(
      ofType(authActions.signIn),
      switchMap(mapSignInAction$)
    )
```

Answer (score 2):

The error is correct because you create `hot()` Observable and then pass it to `signInEpic` method. But `.ofType` doesn't exist on the Observable class, this method is specific to `redux-observable`.

By just quickly looking into the source code you can create a mock `$actions` Observable yourself:

https://github.com/redux-observable/redux-observable/blob/master/src/ActionsObservable.js

For example like this:

```
import { ActionsObservable } from 'redux-observable';

scheduler.run(({ cold, hot, expectObservable }) => {
  const source = hot('-a', { a: { type: 'HFJKDHF' } });
  const actions$ = ActionsObservable.of(source);

  const state$ = null
  const output$ = signInEpic(action$, state$)

  expectObservable(output$).toBe('--b', {
    b: actions.signInSuccess(response);
  });
});
```

Comment: thank you! Do you know why when use hot to create mock stream action in epic doesn't exist action stream, instead action come SubscriptionLoggable ?

Comment: I think I don't understand what problem you have. It's returning `SubscriptionLoggable`?

Comment: Yes, if I remove hot in epic come `{ type: '...', payload: { ... } }` https://imgur.com/W9l6BiX, but with hot come `SubscriptionLoggable` https://imgur.com/nNYjxBP, and when it go through `ofType` there don't exist `{ type: '...', payload: { ... } }`, and epic doesn't call